# Using grep map-reduce program on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, grep, mapreduce

I am using hadoop grep program which comes embedded in the example jar file.

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-examples.jar grep /user/tavasthi/log /user/tavasthi/log_result_output 'ip1 | ip2'
```

But the results are coming wrong. My intention is to search for records in which there is an occurence of ip1 or ip2.

Kindly suggest.

Thanking you in anticipation!
Tapan

Comment: What is wrong with the results? How are they different from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex expression is most probably wrong: `'ip1 | ip2'` should probably be `'(ip1|ip2)'` - noting the lack of whitespace and additional parenthesis around the two terms your are looking for